# Managing environment configuration with ant/svn

Tags: svn, configuration, ant, development-environment

If a project depends on other libraries whose locations are non-standard, where should the locations be stored? My current solution is to have something like this at the top of the Ant build.xml script:

```
<!-- change these properties to point to the correct library locations on your system -->
<property name="lib.foo" location="${user.home}/foo" />
<property name="lib.bar" location="${user.home}/bar" />
```

This works great if your libraries are installed in those locations. However, it is problematic for users that have them installed elsewhere because your changes get blown away when you `svn update`.

What is the best practice for allowing a user's local changes to persist between updates, but at the same time being able to provide default locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a property entry such as:

```
<property file="user.properties" />
```

to the very beginning of your ant script, followed by property entries defining the default values.  (See:  [Ant Docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).)  This technique allows each user to (optionally) override the default values with a local file.

If you add user.properties to the svn:ignore list, then it won't get checked in or modified by SVN and each user can have their own custom version of the file.